# How to configure Spring Security to avoid 'anonymousUser'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security configured as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(Constants.DEVSTACK_SECURITY_ORDER - 1)
    static class WebHttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        /**
         * Configures Application WebSecurity which involves the full Security pipeline (?)
         *
         * @param web WebSecurity
         */
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring()
                    // Allow requests to HealthCheck Endpoint without Bearer Token
                    .antMatchers("/api/healthCheck", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html",
                     "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**", "/api/v1/browser/**", "/swagger-resources/**")
                    // Allow OPTIONS request without Bearer Token (for pre-flight requests)
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        }

        /**
         * Configures HttpSecurity
         *
         * @param http HttpSecurity
         * @throws Exception if an error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    //Authorize INSECURE request to this endpoint (so Swagger can pull the data)
                    .antMatcher("/v2/api-docs")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this Configuration class I'm ignoring certain endpoints from passing through Spring Security, most of them are for Swagger documentation so you can ignore it.

My problem is inside the configure(HttpSecurity) method. I don't know why but the way I wrote it it just works. When I try to understand what I just configured I read it like this:

- For every request to "/v2/api-docs", authorize the requests
- For any other requests, permit them all.

Now I want to add a Custom Filter to the Spring Security Filter Chain.
This is the Filter class:

```
public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                         ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug("MyFilter");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to add the filter to my HttpSecurity, I end up with Spring Security setting my Principal to 'anonymousUser'.

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class);
 }
```

I've tried many different things like:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable();
    }
```

But it still returns 'anonymousUser' when I try to get the user's Principal.

I don't know why having it configured like this works?!?!

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       //Authorize INSECURE request to this endpoint (so Swagger can pull the data)
       .antMatcher("/v2/api-docs")
       .authorizeRequests()
       .anyRequest()
       .permitAll();
}
```

Can someone enlighten me and explain me like i'm five years old? Sometimes I just think I'm too stupid to understand Spring

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
     http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
```

Comment: Hey appreciate your answer, could you try to explain why it should be like that?
I know that the antMatchers order is important so if the first one captures every request then the rest won't work. But aside from that I dont understand the difference between permitAll() and authenticated()

Comment: You are right, the order matters. `authenticated()` protects all paths while `permitAll()` allows it. Except that when `antMatchers(..)` (works in both cases) is specified

Comment: And if I want to add MyFilter to HttpSecurity there shouldn't be any problem, right?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any.

Comment: Hey Aman, thanks again but I tried what you suggested and it isn't working.
I will edit my question with more info.

Comment: Where and how are you trying to get the userPrincipal? And why `WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter`?

Comment: I need to get the userPrincipal every time I make a CRUD operation to save the user in a property 'updatedBy'. My company has a library that does some checking JWT Validation, Security Checks, etc. That library has a very high Order (2147483637).
I want to make every request pass FIRST through that library and THEN through my custom filter. I suspect that I can't add a Custom Filter to that configuration so it can be either before or after that Configuration. Why WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter? Just because it's the first Filter in the SecurityFilterChain, my Custom Filter could be anywhere

Comment: You have to get the *UserPrincipal* from the *SecurityContextHolder*, after a user has logged in. YOu dont have to add any filters if the companies library is doing so.

Comment: I get the UserPrincipal, like this: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
But for every request incoming I must check against my company services if the user has permission to read/edit the request resource. 
That's why I though a Filter would be a good fit, as I need that logic to be executed once per request. I don't know how to configure my SecurityFilterChain so every request pass through my company library then through my filter. I think my current HttpSecurity configuration works because almost every request is not captured by that configuration.

Comment: If you mean *permission* as in *ROLE*, you may add it as `antMatchers(..).hasRole('ROLE_XXX')`. If you mean *permission* as in fine grained page level permissions, this is not the right approach. But, it is a different question, so you have to address it in another question